# Is IntelliJ debugger fooling me?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, boolean

I have a following case:
[image]

So, as you can see, `powerloadIsPresent(powerLoad)` method returns `true` in watcher but debugger actually stopped in `else` section.
I thought that `powerloadIsPresent()` could change it's state but it only checks if it is null or not...

I've been able to reproduce this only once.
Have you got any idea why this might happen?

Thank you in advance for any ideas :)

Comment: Did you check if the return of `powerloadIsPresent(powerLoad)` is actually `true`?

Comment: Yes, I have added a watcher and did return `true`

Comment: But did you also verify in another way the value? Just to exclude that is a problem/bug of IntelliJ?

Comment: I wasn't able to do that - it never happened again

Comment: It won't be a bug in IntelliJ. They write better than we do. The debugger works. I'm curious about "only reproducing it once".  Is this code multithreaded?  It's a problem with the OP's code.

Comment: The executed code might not have lined up with the editor code. Maybe you did not rebuild, or hotswap failed without you noticing.

Comment: @duffymo "It won't be a bug in IntelliJ. They write better than we do" Oh come on... it could be a bug. JetBrains has 306 934 bug issues in their tracker...

Comment: @Meo - yeah, everybody makes mistakes.
It may be an issue with remote debugger (some changes that i did not notice).
Anyway - I suppose we can only speculate - I just thought someone had a simillar issue

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA highlights the line reported by the JVM, if it reports the wrong line, the wrong one will be shown as the current step. Either the sources and classes were not in sync or it was some JVM glitch, you can get [low level debugger logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125-Collecting-Java-debugger-logs) to see which lines are stepped in.

Comment: @Meo - no doubt.  The guys from JetBrains are better than you, me, and the OP. You could never produce something to compare to IntelliIJ.